# Excel Macro with Array for PDF or duplex printing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. Two of those sheets are named "E-ARB" and "WIPL". Each sheet pulls data all throughout the workbook based on an identifying value in a cell on one of those respective sheets ("W01,0", "W02,0", "W03,0", "W04,0"... and so on).

Previously, you had to manually put in the identifying values and print each worksheet page manually (each worksheet comes out to exactly one page). The code I wrote now does allow one to print each worksheet associated with the same identifying value. This way, you run the macro and have multiple print jobs and you're done.

However, I run into two issues:

1. I'd love to have this array save the 'print' as pdf's (one file or individual files - doesn't matter) which I then print duplex on paper (front "E-ABR" and back "WIPL" for W01,0). Unfortunately, when I implement printing to pdf excel does not allow me to run the macro.
2. OR if there's a way to not have the macro split each sheet into a separate printing job, I could be printing duplex straight away. Right now the code is giving me a print out for each worksheet with each identifying value

Here's the code:

```
Sub PrintABR()
Dim i As Integer
Dim VList As Variant

VList = Array("W01,0", "W02,0", "W03,0", "W04,0")
For i = LBound(VList) To UBound(VList)
    Worksheets("E-ABR").Range("D8") = VList(i)
    Worksheets("WIPL").Range("D10") = VList(i)
        Worksheets(Array("E-ABR", "WIPL")).PrintOut
Next
```

End Sub

Any guidance is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Instead of printing to pdf, you can save to pdf as per here: https://www.contextures.com/excelvbapdf.html

Comment: So I had tried that before, however, since the code uses an array it means that you'll have to save the file each time one is generated (since each "W01,0", "W02,0" etc is it's own file). I was hoping to avoid that.